# Error report - ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE TableTwo
(
    OrderNumber NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstSeenDate DATE,
    Street1 VARCHAR(20),
    Street2 VARCHAR(20),
    City VARCHAR(12),
    State VARCHAR(2),
    Zip VARCHAR(5),
    LastModifiedDate DATE 
) ;

INSERT INTO TableTwo (OrderNumber, FirstSeenDate, Street1, City, State, Zip, LastModifiedDate)
VALUES ('1234567899', '2022-08-20', 'P.O BOX 340', 'Boca Raton', 'FL', '33435','2022-10-12');
```

Comment: can anyone help me idk which format they are saying is wrong

Comment: For one - don't put **number** values into single quotes; `INSERT INTO TableTwo (....)
VALUES (1234567899, ......)`

Comment: `'2022-08-20'` is not a date data type; it is a string literal that happens to look like a date. Oracle will implicitly try to convert the string to a date and, in this case, it is failing because, as the error message states, the string literal does not match format string, which is the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a date literal you either need to provide a format mask or use the DATE literal, example:

```
INSERT INTO TableTwo (OrderNumber, FirstSeenDate, Street1,  City, State, Zip, LastModifiedDate)
VALUES ('1234567899', to_date('2022-08-20','YYYY-MM-DD'), 'P.O BOX 340', 'Boca Raton', 'FL', '33435',to_date('2022-10-12','YYYY-MM-DD');
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO TableTwo (OrderNumber, FirstSeenDate, Street1,  City, State, Zip, LastModifiedDate)
VALUES ('1234567899', DATE '2022-08-20', 'P.O BOX 340', 'Boca Raton', 'FL', '33435',  DATE '2022-10-12');
```

If you do not specify as in one of the two above options, oracle will assume the date string is in the format defined by the NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams122.htm#REFRN10119.